# Invalid hook call with gltfjsx

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying out the package `gltfjsx`. I'm trying to run a single command from the documentation:

```
npx gltfjsx model.gltf
```

This command works in the video tutorials I've seen, but gives me this error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This   
       could happen for one of the following reasons:
       1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
       2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
       3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
       See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.). If you meant to render a collection of children,   
       use an array instead.
           in ink-text (created by Text)
           in Text
           in ink-box (created by Box)
           in Box
           in App
           in App
           in InternalApp

 - 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
 - 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
 - 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
 -See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an 
   array instead.
 -     in ink-text (created by Text)
 -     in Text
 -     in ink-box (created by Box)
 -     in Box
 -     in App
 -     in App
 -     in InternalApp
 -throwOnInvalidObjectTyp (C:/Users/Amol/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/16b3f312213fced0/node_modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:452 
                         4:15)
 - createChild (C:/Users/Amol/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/16b3f312213fced0/node_modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:4757:7)        
 -reconcileChildrenArray (C:/Users/Amol/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/16b3f312213fced0/node_modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:5008 
                        :25)
 -reconcileChildFibers (C:/Users/Amol/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/16b3f312213fced0/node_modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:5374:1 
                      4)
 - reconcileChildren (C:/Users/Amol/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/16b3f312213fced0/node_modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:7865:28) 
 -updateHostComponent (C:/Users/Amol/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/16b3f312213fced0/node_modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:8387:3) 

 - beginWork$1 (C:/Users/Amol/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/16b3f312213fced0/node_modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:9969:14)       
 -Object.invokeGuardedCallbackI (C:/Users/Amol/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/16b3f312213fced0/node_modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.development. 
  pl                           js:11563:10)
 -invokeGuardedCallback (C:/Users/Amol/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/16b3f312213fced0/node_modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:11740 
                       :31)
 - beginWork$$1 (C:/Users/Amol/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/16b3f312213fced0/node_modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:15778:7)
```

I'm using this along with next.js, is that somehow related to the problem?

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx/issues/68 ?

Comment: @AKX Yes, same error everytime.